# How to run react script on site?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eos

could someone help me please?
i have got problems with ual-anchor
what i do:

```sh
cd /public_html
yarn add ual-reactjs-renderer
yarn add ual-anchor
```

index.html

```html
<script  type="module" src="./anchor.js">
```

anchor.js

```js
import { Anchor } from './ual-anchor';
import { UALProvider, withUAL } from './ual-reactjs-renderer';
```

and got

> was blocked because of a disallowed mime type (“text/html”).

what is wrong?